# Pasting text to VI adds pound?

Tags: vi

When I paste the following text into VI
VI adds pound to each line, Is there a way around this?

```
####################################
##Parameters for XEROX Printers MSSQL DB 
####################################

## The collation type of the MSSQL database.
xerox.db.collation = UTF-8

## The port of the MSSQL database. Default is 1433.
xerox.db.mssql.port = 1433

## The xerox MSSQL database name.
xerox.db.mssql.name = xerox.datacenter001.prnt0080
```

Comment: When you say "pound" do you mean a pound sign "£" or a hash "#"? And where in the line does it add this "pound" sign? I don't see anything wrong with the file snippet you've included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:set paste` should do the trick.

`#` denotes a commented line in your file.

`:set paste` will turn off auto-indenting and auto-commenting, which will allow you to copy and paste things into vi without vi automatically adding comments to the beginning of lines after a line you are pasting that has a comment.

You can run `:set nopaste` again to turn the setting back off.

Comment: Does `set: paste` really toggle it? Shouldn't it be `set: nopaste` to turn it off?

Comment: Whoops, good call. Updating answer now.